# Nested Views using backbone.marionette

Tags: kendo-ui, marionette, single-page-application

In my SPA using backbone.marionette I am trying to render a CompositeView inside tab of an other CompositeView.

I have successfully rendered the control **but events are not being registered in DOM**

Here is my code sample:

**MainView: view.js  (that received the subView and render it inside tab)**

```js
define(["marionette", "backbone", "kendo", "../SubView/view"],
    function (Marionette, Backbone, kendo, subView) {
        var View = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
            template: "MainView/template.t",            
            onRender: function () {

        var tabStrip = this.$("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip().data("kendoTabStrip");                
                    tabStrip.append({
                        text: "Sub View",
                        content: new subView().render().$el.html()
                    });

            },
            onShow: function () {
                //Set Default Active Tab
                var tabStrip = $('#tabStrip').data().kendoTabStrip;
                tabStrip.select(0);
            },
        });

        return View;
```

---

### MainView: template.t

```html
<div id="tabStrip"></div>
```

---

### SubView: view.js

```js
define(["marionette", "backbone", "kendo"],
    function (Marionette, Backbone, kendo) {
        var View = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
            template: "SubView/template.t",            
            },            
            onRender: function () {
                var data = [{ Description: "Test 1", ID: 1 }, { Description: "Test 2", ID: 2 }]
                this.$("#ddlTest").kendoDropDownList({
                    dataSource: data,
                    dataTextField: "Description",
                    dataValueField: "ID",
                });                
                return this;
            },
        });

        return View;
    });
```

---

### SubView: template.t

```html
<input id="ddlTest"/>
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you arent even listening for any events, so I'm not sure what the question is.